# Android Installed PWA not showing window.location.href

Tags: android, vue.js, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

i have a issue where my PWA is not going to show me `window.location.href` after installation on my Android device.

i was having a Web-App where after someone has a active sessions, and is going to install the App on its device, the PWA opens and shows him a 404 page.

My Vue.js web app processes all routes that lead to nirvana with a '404, this page does not exist!'

After installing the PWA, the 404 page is opening for no reason. To figure out why, i need to know which URL is getting shown when opening the PWA. but i can't do this because it's on my real mobile device and there i can't see a URL because of the PWA feature.